# PyCharm ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turtle'

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, modulenotfounderror

I am new to programming and wanted to use turtle in PyCharm (Community Edition 2020.3). I am running Pop-OS 20.10.

This is what I entered:

```py
import turtle
s = turtle.getscreen()
```

This is what I got from PyCharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/przvl/PycharmProjects/Introduction/Turtle Car.py", line 3, in <module>
      import turtle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turtle'
```

I installed tkinter with:

```sh
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

I can run turtle from the CLI:

[image: turtle running in CLI]

PyCharm is set to the correct Python interpreter (as far as I know):

[image: PyCharm Interpreter settings]

Comment: As seen in the last screenshot, the Pycharm project is using a virtual environment. Fixing the base Python installation (`sudo apt install python3-tk`) will not necessarily update virtual environments, because they may have their own copies of files instead of completely symlinking the base Python. In this case, it is necessary to re-create the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpreter settings show you did not installed turtle in the virtual environment that Pycharm is configured to work with.

Two options:

1. Recommended - install `turtle' on the venv (u can just "+" in the pycharm)
2. Configure Pycharm to work with your system python to where you have probably installed turtle.

Comment: I can't add turtle manually to the venv. Clicking the "+" for adding packages and searching for "turtle" only gives another, completely unrelated package of the same name ("HTTP Proxy to throttle connections..."). Using command "type -a python3.8" gave two directories "python3.8 is /usr/bin/python3.8" and "/bin/python3.8". I tried setting both in PyCharm and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading PyCharm from jetbrains.com and manually installing it via the CLI. The interpreter now works correctly and I can use turtle.

Previously, I used Pop-OS inbuilt Shop and flatpak installation of the program, which seems to cause trouble for some users.